# Node Hostname in Prometheus Alert email

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Is there any way to add Host-name in Prometheus alert email, along with IP address and Port. current alert configuration is as follows:

```
  - alert: instance_down
    expr: 'up{job="node_exporter"} == 0'
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      title: 'Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down'
      description: >-
        {{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for
        more than 1 minute.
```

`$labels.instance`  gives output like `192.168.1.10:9100`. Is it possible to insert Node Host-name along with this description.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the target discovery system you are using.

If you are using a static config list, you can use the hostname instead of the IP address. If you are using another system, register the target with the hostname.

Then, you can add a relabel config to extract the hostname from the label containing the instance `host:port`.

For example, if the label is `__address__` contains `host:port`, you can add a rule like this:

```
relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__address__]
  target_label: host
  regex: (.*):(.*)
  replacement: $1
```